# Redirect the output to two processes and merge

Tags: bash

Background:  sometimes I use `ps aux | grep process_name` to figure out some statistics of a process.  But I can't remember the headers of ps output.  So I need to do:

```
ps aux | tee 1.txt | grep process_name > 2.txt
cat 1.txt | head -1 | cat - 2.txt
```

So my questions is: is there a way to achieve this without the two temporary files, and preferably use one line of commands instead of two lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is just to use something a bit smarter than `grep`. For example:

```
ps aux | perl -ne 'print if $. == 1 || m/process_name/'
```

will print the first line of `ps aux`'s output, plus any line that matches `process_name` (which is a Perl regular expression — more powerful than POSIX BRE's, and therefore more complicated, but I don't think you'll find any surprises if you're just searching for a process name).

**Edited to add:** For that matter, since `ps aux`'s headers are unlikely to change between runs, you could write:

```
ps aux | head -1 ; ps aux | grep process_name
```

though I don't know if that still counts as "one line of commands". :-)

**More options:** Since you don't like the above, here are some more. This one will read and print the first line directly, and then leave the rest for `grep` to read and process:

```
ps aux | ( ( read -r LINE ; echo "$LINE" ) ; grep process_name )
```

This one will cause every line to be written both to standard output (file descriptor `1`) and to a custom file descriptor (`3`); then `head` gets standard output, while `grep` gets what was written to the custom file descriptor:

```
( ( ps aux | while read -r LINE ; do echo "$LINE" ; echo "$LINE" 1>&3 ; done | head -1 1>&4 ) 3>&1 | grep process_name ) 4>&1
```

That one is the most general way that I know of to do what you're asking for — at least, using only Bash builtins and features — but as you can see, it's quite unwieldy, which is why I recommend the simpler ways when you don't need the full power of this approach. Also, that last one no longer guarantees that headers come first; on my system, the output of `head` seems to consistently end up *after* the output of `grep`. (I suppose that could be addressed by swapping the positions of the `head` and `grep` commands, but that still wouldn't be reliable so far as I know, and it seemed to have weird effects when I tried it just now.)

Comment: This looks good, and I'll accept it if there is no other answers.  But there is still other cases I want to split the output into two or more processes and want to merge the output later.  I wonder if there is some more BASH way of doing that.

Comment: @icando: I've added some more options, including one that really does split the output into two or more processes . . . but it's kind of a mess!

Comment: Sorry tried your last option, but doesn't work.
`[hidden]$ ( ( ps aux | while read -r LINE ; do echo "$LINE" ; echo "$LINE" 1>&3 ; done | head -1 1>&4 ) 3>&1 | grep bash ) 4>&1
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND`
And I did have `bash`

Comment: @icando: Yeah, I was getting a somewhat similar behavior when I tried swapping the `grep` and the `head`: some of the `grep` output would randomly disappear. I don't know if it and `head` were writing to the same output-buffer, or what. But when I had `head` and `bash` in the order in my answer -- which is what you tried -- I *didn't* have that problem. So it seems like the concept works, but the realization is unreliable. :-/

Comment: @icando: Yeah, and I'll keep thinking about it. Maybe after I've slept on it I'll have a better idea what's going wrong. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Or, since I never remember perl or awk without looking it up:

```
ps aux | head -n 1 && ps aux |grep process_name
```

Comment: This works in this case but what if it is not `ps aux` but some other command that can't be run twice, or just produces different result for two runs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "...that can't be run twice".  If the first part failed, you mean?  The intent of the first part is just to spit out the headers (should work with things like lsof, too) - it shouldn't fail, unless I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1):

Another dirty trick is to memorize that the header starts with `'USER'` and do

```
ps aux | grep -E 'USER | process_name'
```

This will also show the `grep` command itself :)

Comment: … or `ps aux | grep -E '^USER | .{40,}process_name'` … which shouldn't hit any spurious other lines, since they'll begin with usernames. Unless you have a user named USER. The .{40,} should (on any `ps` I know) miss false-positives on users whose name match the process, as well (the COMMAND column has always been at column 40+ in my experience)

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
ps aux | egrep "(^USER +PID)|^process_name"
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` will do exactly what you want:

```
ps aux | sed -n -e '1 p; /PROCESS_NAME/p'
```

The `sed` command line:

`-n` print only the specified lines
  `-e` execute the following script
  `1 p` print the first line
  `;` command separator
   `/PROCESS_NAME/p` print lines containing `PROCESS_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

use the name(s) of processes with -C

```
ps u -C java -C totem
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
stefan   16878  0.1 10.5 429036 107868 pts/7   Sl+  12:51   0:24 /opt/java/bin/java -Xmx256M -Xms32M -Xbootclasspa
stefan   25791  0.5  3.8 202800 38984 ?        Sl   17:45   0:16 totem file:///home/stefan/Desktop/scala/dritte/dl
```

I hope this doesn't only work on Linux. :)

I'm always baffled to see, how many people don't know (or use) the options of **ps** - maybe there are too many? It's always `ps | grep x`. :)